# Scale on <a> elements with tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

Should hover:scale e.g. hover:scale-125 work on `<a>` elements when using tailwind CSS.
I'm running a Django project... it works on `<div>`'s `<img>`'s and other elements but not on `<a>`...

It that how it is or is something wrong with my tailwind css?

Thanks!

tested this scale on other elements and it worked, but it doesn't on `<a>` elements

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tag is an [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#list_of_inline_elements) element and cannot be scaled

`img` is also inline element but Tailwind [set](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#images-are-block-level) `display: block` property on images in preflight styles

In order to take effect you should other `display` property - like `inline-block`, `block`, `flex` etc

See [DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/qjJgFrRvn5)